# Vb6 ADODC Login failed for the user knows in Windows 7

Tags: sql-server, windows-7, vb6, truedbgrid

I have a vb6 project with a form with a `Apex TruedbGrid 6` Oledb datasource that has as an ADODC (Ado 6.0 sp6) on the same form.

`cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI.1;Data Source=pc-musica;Initial Catalog=QdE;User ID=sa;Password=*******"`

In Form_Load :

```
Adodc.ConnectionString = cn.ConnectionString
Adodc.RecordSource = "Select Code, Description from Cantine"
Adodc.Refresh
```

When executes last statement `Adodc.Refresh` only on Windows 7 (because everything works quietly in Xp) gives me the error:

`Login failed for the user, type: -2147217843 Automation Error.`

I checked the connection string and it is also right when the program uses the same connection to open a recordset and operates quietly.

The connection is declared in a module.

How do you think I can fix on Windows 7 32 bit?

Answer (score 1):

You should add attribute on the string with ; `Persist Security Info=true`

That happens because on Windows Vista or Windows 7 has a new security fix, that causes error on the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [bug report](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304310) that this can happen if you have a password with trailing spaces.  Their suggestion is:

> To work around this problem, use the OLE DB Provider for ODBC Driver
>   instead of the OLE DB Provider for SQL Server, or do not create
>   passwords with trailing spaces.

If that's not it, you might try rewriting it with a different provider anyway.  Or replace the grid.  I've had some trouble getting VB6 to behave on Windows 7.

Comment: In my password don't have trailing spaces and Even with the OleDb Provider does not work